# SysAllocString/SysFreeString COM functions require CoInitialize to be called?

Tags: windows, com

Is it required for COM to be initialized to use SysAllocString, SysFreeString and other BSTR handling functions?

The MSDN says

> You need to initialize the COM library on a thread before you call any of the library functions except CoGetMalloc

It appears to me that BSTR allocation functions use IMalloc and therefore COM init is not required?

Comment: Where did you see that BSTR allocation uses IMalloc?. In MSDN I found this: "Automation may cache the space allocated for BSTRs. This speeds up the SysAllocString/SysFreeString sequence. However, this may also cause IMallocSpy to assign leaks to the wrong memory user because it is not aware of the caching done by Automation." I wonder if this caching process does not require COM initialization.

Comment: On any case, I do not see what benefit you could get by *not* following what the documentation says...

Comment: I read about IMalloc somewhere on the net while studying this question. The benefit is that my software heavily uses BSTR's in different threads (many of them) and should I make sure all of them do call Co(Un)Initialize or it's not necessary.

Comment: I don't think your "therefore" is well-grounded. Also, why not do initialization if are about to use these functions.

Comment: It is a fairly pointless question.  BSTR is a COM Automation type, you can never run Automation code without CoInitializeEx().  It is not like you won't find out, CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED keeps you honest.  Not checking error codes is the kind of dishonesty you'll always regret, that does include checking the return value of SysAllocString().  What's left to fret about is somebody else's code being dishonest, a very common bug you'll always regret :)

Comment: @Hans SysAllocString call is successful without COM initialization.

Comment: Yes, so what?  What matters is what you are going to *do* with that BSTR.  If you don't have to pass it to a function that requires a BSTR argument then there wasn't any point in using SysAllocString().  If you do pass it to such a function then it is excessively likely that CoInitializeEx() had to be called to make that function work properly.  You don't necessarily get a good error code from that function, you didn't write it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. I use BSTRs to communicate between DLLs, not to call some COM functions.

Comment: Then why is the question tagged as `COM`? When you talk about BSTR type in C/C++ it is just an alias for `wchar_t*` so you can say that you don't even need `SysAllocString`/`SysFreeString` to use `BSTR` to communicate beween DLLs.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic BSTRs are not ordinary strings: they're length-prefixed, so if *any* code expects an actual BSTR and tries to do something with it that only BSTRs support...

Comment: @Zdeslav, no. The BSTRs are used to communicate between modules  written in different languages. I was not asking what string type to use, anyway. Please read the original question.

Comment: @Medinoc, yes, I know that - I am saying that from C++ POV, there is nothing special about `BSTR` - it doesn't have any behavior, as it is just alias for widechar pointer. OP says he is not using them in COM context. My point is that it is strange to talk about COM requirements, when COM is not being used.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find official documentation that says you can call these functions without initializing COM but I can take you on a trip down memory lane for some cute observations.

Because Windows 95 ran on machines with 4 MB of RAM, Explorer tries really hard not to load ole32.dll. So hard in fact that the shell team wrote their own mini version of COM and people writing shell extensions were supposed to only call SH* functions, not Co* functions to avoid loading the real COM/OLE stuff if possible.

[This blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040705-00/?p=38573) says that mini-COM is 100% gone in Windows XP and later but I'm not sure how far back it is theoretically possible for the shell to be in mini-COM mode.

Things get interesting when you realize that Windows 2000 has a shell interface called IShellFolder2 and one of its methods ([GetDetailsEx](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775051)) returns a VARIANT. And VARIANTs can contain a BSTR! IColumnProvider::GetItemData also returns a VARIANT.

With this information you could infer that Windows 2000 could allocate a BSTR without you having to call CoInitialize, just call SHGetDesktopFolder to get a IShellFolder and ask for a property that is returned as a string.

There are however two unknowns here:

- Is it possible for Windows 2000 to use mini-COM?
- Will the IShellFolder2 implementation in shell32.dll initialize real COM if it has to return a string?

I know that IShellFolder2 and IColumnProvider are involved when a Explorer window is in details mode (or if it needs a tooltip?) so it seems unlikely that the shell would be willing to load real COM for this.

Even if I could confirm all of this it would not really help you because I assume your main target is not Windows 2000.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I think I found the answer to this question, experimentally. I forgot to update it here. In short - NO, SysAlloc/FreeString functions can't be used without COM being initialized. Doing so leads to random Access Violations, it starts to happen only if the program runs for extended periods of time, like 3-7 days.